# Using LightGM-webkit-greeter and get dark screen

Tags: themes, lightdm, login-screen

OS: Ubuntu 18.04
I want to change login screen, so I do the following:

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm-webkit-greeter
nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
/*
[SeatDefaults] 
greeter-session=lightdm-webkit-greeter 
allow-guest=false
*/
// Download a theme from github
git clone *****/aqua.git
sudo mv auqa /usr/share/lightdm-webkit/themes/aqua
nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm-webkit-greeter.conf
// change one line
// webkit-theme=aqua
reboot
```

And the result is I can only see a black screen with a cursor.

How can I recover from this situation(go back to default)?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I believe the only option for you is to reinstall Ubuntu 18.04 or somehow getting into the safe mode. I'm new to ubuntu since using 20.10 and then down to 20.04 but in the Ubuntu installer, I believe that in the 18.04 installer, there is an option for reinstalling ubuntu and clean out all programs but keep your music, photos and other personal files you stored on ubuntu. You use that option and make sure to not repeat the same mistake afterwards and precisely follow instructions. Hope that helps!